# How can make my server calculate the result even after the user exits the website and store it to database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backend, serverside-javascript

So basically I am working on a react project with firebase as back-end and authentication. This project is a prediction platform where user registers and predicts whether gold price will go up or down.

So when a user click on prediction (for example- price will go up by $5) and exits the site, I have the api to compare current price with predicted price but how can I compare it without user using the website (on the server) and store it to database.

Thanks in advance and apologies if I haven't expressed it clearly.

Comment: Maybe you can add a cleanup step in useEffect hook and invoke a api call while leaving so the server will take care of calculating and storing the value

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not a code-writing service and can only assist with existing code. So, write some code to perform that task and when you get stuck, post your code, troubleshooting and Firebase structure and we'll take a look!